# get text in XML files in a folder one by one with XML elementTree

Tags: python, xml, text, iteration, elementtree

I want to get the main text (text of <p> tags in <body> tag, there is a number of them) from all xml files in a folder one by one, actually, I want to save it in the same file, so it is kind of deleting some contents from an XML file and only keep desired part. Folder "/home/xml_folder", below is my code, it prints text of one xml file again and again, I guess iteration did not work. Code:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
import os

## iterate all xml files in folder one by one:
path = '/home/xml_files'
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if not filename.endswith('.xml'): continue
    tree = ET.parse(filename)
    root = tree.getroot()
    print(root)
    while True:
        try:
            for element in root.iter():
                if(element.tag == 'p'):
                print(element.text[2:])
        except TypeError:
            continue
```

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are not breaking the while loop. So it keeps on printing the same thing. Insert a break statement after for loop in try block of while loop.

Comment: @SURYATEJA, thank you, instead of insert BREAK statement after the for loop. I just deleted the while loop. it woks. how about saving text to SAME FILE, could you help!

Comment: please make a copy of ur xml files before executing this script as this overwrites ur existing file. `from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
import os

path = '/home/xml_files'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
  if not filename.endswith('.xml'): continue
  tree = ET.parse(filename)
  root = tree.getroot()
  print(root)
  paragraph = ''
  try:
    for element in root.iter():
        if(element.tag == 'p'):
           paragraph=paragraph+element.text[2:]
    with open(f'/home/xml_files/{filename}','w') as file:
        file.write(paragraph)
  except TypeError:
    continue`

Comment: @SURYATEJA, thank you, it worked for me.